# Why is a filter scanning my attachment (.xlsx) declaring it as a xls

Tags: excel, filter, xlsx, xls

A filter is declaring my .xlsx as an .xls because of the mime type found in the file
mime type : application/vnd.ms-office

im kinda confused?

I tried to change the xlsx or resend it again but still the same anyone knows if the vnd.ms-office is may declaring the file as a .xls?